# How do I find the dot product of two 3d vectors which are lists and as args in a class, in which I have used __mul__?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code where only in `__mul__` do I have a problem...

```
class Vector:
 def __init__(self, vector):
    self.vector = vector
    ##here lies the issue

 def __mul__(self, other):
    if len(self.vector) != len(other.vector):


 #differentiating scalar multiplication of a single num and a vector versus 
 #dot product of 2 vectors

           return Vector([a*other for a in self.vector])
     __rmul__ = __mul__ 


 # found this on this website and it worked amazingly Thank you khelwood for 
 # scalar! But this doesnt solve dot product!!!

     else:
         return sum(i[0] * i[1] for i in zip(self.vector,other.vector))
```

Sum never works for dot product. I don't know why? How do I find the dot product of two vectors? I can multiply each individual number of both lists using zip but the sum of the final list doesnt work!
Am I missing something here?
A link that kinda helped but did't:
http://www.pradeepadiga.me/blog/2017/04/18/finding-dot-product-in-python-without-using-numpy/
Sorry if this is a dumb question:(.

Comment: Also there is no point in having this line `__rmul__ = __mul__`, the code never gets there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The

```
__rmul__ = __mul__
```

appears to be in the wrong spot in your post.
It should really be

```
def __rmul__(self, other):
   self.__mul__(other)
```

## Edit:

> This error keeps popping up still....Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users...Classess.py", line 43, in  print(x*5==Vector([10, 20, 30])) File "C:...Classess.py", line 25, in **mul** if len(self.vector) != len(other.vector): AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'vector'

From one of your comments to someone else. He replied and is correct. This is failing in the case of scalar multiplication of 'ints' don't have a 'vector' property. This will be the case for a vector being multiplied by an integer:

```
x = Vector(1,2,3)
y = x * 5
```

The above will fail due to the error check in the if statement. 5 has no property vector. You need to first check that other is not an int, if it is an int then you perform your scalar multiplication of the vectors. Change:

```
 if len(self.vector) != len(other.vector):
```

to

```
if type(other) is int:
   ...
```

## Edit 2:

I'll try what someone else has tried but slightly differently.

```
class Vector:
 def __init__(self, vector):
    self.vector = vector
    ##here lies the issue
 def __rmul__(self,other):
    return self.__mul__(other)

 def __mul__(self, other):
    if type(other) is int:
           return Vector([a*other for a in self.vector])
    else:
         return sum(i[0] * i[1] for i in zip(self.vector,other.vector))
```

Test it with:

```
x = Vector((1,2,3))
y = Vector((3,2,1))
z = 5
print(y*x)
print(x*y)
print(z*y)
print(y*z)
```

Also, as pointed out my first suggestion won't actually change the output of the code. It has since been changed.

Comment: if i remove the dot product the whole code works, but I cant perform dot product.

Comment: How do I perform a dot product?

Comment: That's not the cause of the OP's problem. You can pass `sum` a generator expression, so your 1st 2 lines should give the same output.

Comment: You are right. I can perform a scalar product of a number and a vector but not dot product of 2 vectors. Is there anything I should change to get  the output?

Comment: instead of if len(self.vector) != len(other.vector):   --->if isinstance(other.vector,(int,float)):

Comment: If not is there anything that would make this work? ANything...Im so close yet so far.......

Comment: @CooperCampbell is there a way to find the dimensions of the inputted vector or rather the object?

Comment: @kalpla You could find the dimensions, only after checking for the object. You must first check for the object because the type int will fail if you try to find the dimensions as you have done. What exactly are you aiming to do with the dimensions?